# How can I get Eclipse to open the entire file when opening search results?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using what I think is an older version of the Eclipse IDE because of a requirement at work to use it. It's version Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). When I do a file search and get a list of search results, I can double-click to open a result. The problem is that if I double-click on the result itself, the editor limits me to edit the function with the search result or some area around the result and I can't scroll to the top and bottom of the file; The editor limits what I can see and edit. If I double-click to open the file then I am, of course, not on a line with a search result. I can't seem to find a setting or preference to alter this behavior. I would like to open the entire file but be on the line with the search result. Does anyone know of a setting to change this behavior?

If there is no way to stop this behavior, is there a way to make the editor show the entire file once the file is open?

I have only been using .java files. I attached an image showing what happens when I open a search result and you can see that there is no scroll bar because the entire function fits in the window. The line numbers are accurate and the rest of the file above and below this function are not visible and I can't get to them without closing and reopening the file.

[image]

Comment: Certainly doesn't happen with the current version. Since Oxygen is 6 years and 22 releases old I don't remember much about it but I don't think this was a normal feature in that release. Do you use the "mylyn" plug-ins - they had things to focus on particular methods.

Comment: Double click to open the file, then perform a second, separate search of just that file to find the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds normal if you are in the Java **Browsing** perspective, or if the **Java**/**Editor** preference page has the "Only show the selected Java element" setting enabled.

Comment: I thought I had seen and unchecked the "Only show selected Java element" option. But apparently I didn't do it or didn't do it right. That was the answer.